# Codeignitor: Where are the docs for :segment? As in $routes->get('(:segment)'

Tags: codeigniter

I figured out that the :segment refers to a piece of the url. In the controllers, for the sample app, we have this:

```
use App\Controllers\News;
use App\Controllers\Pages;

$routes->get('news/(:segment)', [News::class, 'view']);
$routes->get('news', [News::class, 'index']);
$routes->get('pages', [Pages::class, 'index']);
$routes->get('(:segment)', [Pages::class, 'view']);
```

But I cant find any docs for this or there might be other things I can do with it.